# Android parse json force stopped

Tags: android, json

I am parsing a json url: http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQmwsOmYeq?indent=2 but I failed to make it happen. I am getting an error. What's wrong with this code?

```
public void parseJsonResponse(String result) {
    Log.i(TAG, result);
    pageCount++;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("name");
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            CountryInfor country = new CountryInfor();
            country.setId(jObject.getString("id"));
            country.setName(jObject.getString("name"));
            countries.add(country);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("name");
```

these two lines by

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Also change

```
country.setId(jObject.getString("id"));
```

by

```
country.setId(jObject.getInt("id") + "");
```

> Because `id` is of type `int` not a `String`.

And it will work fine.

You are getting response like

```
[
    {
        "id": ​1,
        "name": "Vietnam"
    },
    {
        "id": ​2,
        "name": "China"
    },
    {
        "id": ​3,
        "name": "USA"
    },
    {
        "id": ​4,
        "name": "England"
    },
    {
        "id": ​10,
        "name": "Russia"
    }
]
```

So the response is `JSONArray` and not `JSONObject`.

Hope it'll help.

**Edit**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // call load JSON from url method
    if(loadJSON(this.url) != null) {
        return loadJSON(this.url).toString();
    }
    Log.d("LoadJSONFromUrl", "Failed to get JSONObject.");
    return null;
}
```

You are getting `JSONObject` null, so the error is.

### - You should know [what is `NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I am getting this error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 404 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: paste whole logcat, so that i can get more info about the error.

Comment: You got `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `LoadCountriesFromUrlTask.java:53` which is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: check the answer and try to learn from the provided answer in link.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with this line

```
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("name");
```

There is no array with name `name`. it is failing here. Correct this part to obtain the array properly. Rest looks fine.